# Calling a knockout function from jsTree event

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jstree

I am using jsTree to populate a treeView from ajax. When I click a node on the tree I want to display associated data using knockout.

here is my viewmodel

```
function PanelSearchVM() {
    var self = this;

    self.Panel = ko.observable();
    self.Source = ko.observable();
    self.Substation = ko.observable();
    self.Bay = ko.observable();
    self.Voltage = ko.observable();
    self.Utility = ko.observable();
    self.Train = ko.observable();
    self.kVA = ko.observable();
    self.Drawing = ko.observable();
    self.Status = ko.observable();
    self.ShowT2 = ko.observable();

    self.circuits = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.circuitsT2A = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.circuitsT2B = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.getID = function (data) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Panel/LoadPan",
            data: { "panID": data.node.id },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {


                // This callback is executed if the post was successful   
                console.log("return" + data.PanelDetails[0].Panel);
                self.Panel("test");
                self.Source(data.PanelDetails[0].Source);
                self.Substation(data.PanelDetails[0].Substation);
                self.Bay(data.PanelDetails[0].Bay);
                self.Voltage(data.PanelDetails[0].Voltage);
                self.Utility(data.PanelDetails[0].Utility);
                self.Train(data.PanelDetails[0].Train);
                self.kVA(data.PanelDetails[0].kVA);
                self.Drawing(data.PanelDetails[0].Drawing);
                self.Status(data.PanelDetails[0].Status);


                //Start Panel Type 2

            }
        });

    };



};

ko.applyBindings(new PanelSearchVM());
```

and here is my jquery jsTree event call to the knockout function

```
  var myVM = new PanelSearchVM();

    $('#using_json_2').on("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {


        myVM.getID(data);


    });
```

The code is executing fine and when I click on a node the ko function gets called and returns data. The console logs the returned data. However, the view is not getting updated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're constructing two instances of your view model, through:

```
ko.applyBindings(new PanelSearchVM());
```

and

```
var myVM = new PanelSearchVM();
```

So whilst you update the values in one, the actual HTML is bound to an entirely separate object.  Just instantiate one object:

```
var myVM = new PanelSearchVM();
ko.applyBindings(myVM);
```